# LCD panels used in projectors - What are their limitations?

Tags: lcd, light

It's important I point out immediately that I am an absolute novice at all this. I am trying to self-teach myself the basics by building things but it is a slow slow process. So please bear with me if my questions come across dumb.

I am currently learning how projectors work and decided to look at LCD projectors first as opposed to DLP (DMD) as they appeared to be far more complicated.

**My question is this:**

With the LCD panels being used in these projectors (3 of them), what are their limitations in terms of light?

Are the panels adjusted based off the lumens output from the light in the projector or is it more a "one size fits all" scenario and no matter how much light you shine through the LCD panel, it will produce the same image, just much brighter or dimmer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thermal limitation is what kills them. How much UV and IR can you keep off them and what hurricane speed airflow can you direct across them?

Comment: Thanks winny. Any hard facts about thermal limitations for their breaking points? Are the LCD panels used in the higher lumen projectors any different than the ones in lower lumen projectors in terms of thermal limitations? Or what other tricks do they use to keep those UV and IR figures down?

Comment: Usually slightly bigger, more airflow past them and better IR and UV filtering. Industry has almost completely shifted to DLP, especially at high luminous flux levels and let us poor shmuks suffer the rain low flicker except for the few 3DLP.

Comment: So is DLP able to resist higher heat levels then? How does LCoS compare to LCD and DLP in terms of heat limitations?

You also mentioned better IR and UV filtering. Is this an expensive addition monetary wise or is it a light reduction cost that is the problem from adding more filters?

Comment: Yes! No polarizer light loss = less heat. Your question is getting broader and broader. UHP mercury lamps produce a shitton of UV which you can spend varying amount of money on filtering out. Moving up in luminous flux will lead you to xenon bulbs, which are far more expensive but gives less UV relative to their luminous flux.

Comment: Sorry for broadening the question, your answers make me more and more curious. Thanks for helping out!

I would presume then, that todays electronic flash units would destroy an lcd panel at high flux outputs that they have? Or is that a different matter entirely?

Is there somewhere that I could read more on this that explains it fully? What is the terminology used here for measuring UV and IR output and thermal ouput? Thanks again!